# Determine for which constants $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ it is true that $f \circ g = g \circ f$.

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = ax + b$ and $g(x) = cx^2 + dx$ where $a,b,c,d$ are constants. Determine for which constants $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ it is true that $f \circ g = g \circ f$. I have the equations for $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$.

$$\begin{align}f\circ g&=acx^2+adx+b\\g\circ f&=ca^2x^2-2cabx+cb^2+dax+db\end{align} $$

Comment: Well, I have gotten the f ◦ g and g ◦ f. I do not know how to proceed further as the equations are long

Comment: You set them equal, expand, and simplify.

Comment: Yes I need help in that.

Comment: For example, the coefficients of $x^2$ must be the same. What does thois tell you? (Distinguish the case $c\ne0$ and $c=0$) - Then the same for the coeficients of $x$ and of rthe constant terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternate pproach: Compute a few nice test values to obtain conditions. For exmaple $f(g(0))=g(f(0))$ gives you immediately that $b=cb^2+db=(cb+d)b$, which is true if and only if $b=0$ or $cb+d=0$. Try some other values for $x$, e.g. $x=1$ or $x=-\frac ba$ or $x=-\frac db$. Then combine the condtions obtained.

Comment: ok so here's what I have come with
if you make `c=0` like you said, you can simplify the equation and get `d = 1`
then because `a` and `b` are always with `c` it doesn't matter what values they have since they get multiplied by 0 this making the two sides equal. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = ax + b$ and $g(x) = cx^2 + dx$

$f \circ g = g \circ f = f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$

$a(cx^2 +dx) + b = c(ax+b)^2 +d(ax+b)$

Solve!